# Is a non-Muslim allowed to make Dua?

Tags: non-muslim, dua

A friends family member has passed and I was asked to make Dua. I’m not Muslim so I looked it up but am I allowed to do so? I didn’t want to be rude and reject without knowing for sure.

Comment: Obviously, anyone can make dua until he/she believes in God. I mean, if one doesn't believe in God then whom is he/she making Dua to..??

Comment: As per Islam all of us have same God. Dua means prayer. It is a personal act between you and God. You do not need anybody's permission for it. So the idea of it being allowed or not allowed does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can make dua, disbelieving/non muslim satan (ibliz) made a dua to reprieve him till day of judgement.  Allah accepted his dua.

dua is accepted from non muslims, with following conditions 1. Sincerity 2. He should ask justful thing, (let me win 1 million lottery is not justful dua)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. It's so nice of you to do so.

Comment: This answer is entirely opinion based. Please provide facts and references that support your answer. Nonetheless, once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to Salat, Dua is a free form of praying that is not specific to Islam; Christians and Jews and other religions who pray to God also know free forms of prayer which are not necessaryly different from Dua of Muslim. If Christians pray to God (not Jesus or Mary or someone else), it may also be shared. At least, we already did so; it may not be common everywhere.

Someone who does not believe in God may stay present if others are praying; he may accept to be included in Dua but should not pretend to pray.